# Anbox isn't starting up on my PC at all

Tags: 16.10, snap, anbox

I know it's a relatively new and unstable application but I figured if anyone has suffered through the issue and solved it then they can help me

**The Problem**

when I click on the Anbox icon from gnome app drawer it stays in launcher for 5 secs or so and disappears but it doesn't launch

[GitHub source](https://github.com/anbox/anbox)

[Official Website](http://anbox.io/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What worked for me is running the session manager then clicking on the icon.

first run session manager by entering this command

```
anbox session-manager
```

and then click on the Anbox icon from launcher

Better way would be to add this service inside **Startup Applications**

to do that open Startup Applications > Add > in command write `anbox session-manager`

and you'd be able to use Anbox without running that command on every boot or keeping a minimised terminal windows.

[image: Start up Application]

Comment: That really did the trick

Comment: I have try it, but it give me such message "/snap/anbox/71/usr/bin/anbox: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-8.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". What should I do now?