# Anbox can't be started

Tags: android, emulation, anbox

I am very curious about the new Anbox emulator for running Android apps on PC. Unfortunately I can't make it work on my PC.

After having installed via snap there is a new entry in the Gnome menu list. When I use it, nothing happens. I then tried to start it via terminal with the result, but at least some output.

Starting the session manager seems to work. This step was recommended in a previous question close to mine ([Anbox isn't starting up on my PC at all](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903924/anbox-isnt-starting-up-on-my-pc-at-all)).

```
anbox session-manager
```

Session manager can be started without error or any message. It just seems to run an Android instance fine, which I even can access with adb shell.

Anbox demon ("anboxd") and Init-Script ("anbox-init.sh") are running, too (checked with "ps -A").

But when I try to start Anbox Launcher, the Launcher cannot be started:

```
anbox launch
[WW 2017-04-14 17:46:12] [launch.cpp:115@operator()] Stop waiting as we're already waiting for too long. Something is wrong
[WW 2017-04-14 17:46:12] [launch.cpp:116@operator()] with your setup and the container may have failed to boot.
```

Same result when I start the Anbox icon from launcher (here I started it via shell):

```
anbox launch --package=org.anbox.appmgr
[WW 2017-07-05 15:26:54] [launch.cpp:194@operator()] Stopped waiting as we've already waited for too long. Something
[WW 2017-07-05 15:26:54] [launch.cpp:195@operator()] is wrong with your setup or the container has failed to boot.
[WW 2017-07-05 15:26:54] [launch.cpp:196@operator()] If you think you found a bug please don't hesitate to file on
[WW 2017-07-05 15:26:54] [launch.cpp:197@operator()] at https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/new
```

Any ideas? As you can see, the above mentioned other response does not work.. Thank you in advance! Spectas

PS: some system infos:

```
anbox system-info
version: 0.1.0
os:
  name: Ubuntu Core
  version: 16
  snap-based: true
kernel:
  version: Linux version 4.4.0-53-generic (buildd@lcy01-28) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016
  binder: true
  ashmem: true
graphics:
  egl:
    vendor: Mesa Project
    version: 1.5 (DRI2)
    extensions:
      - EGL_CHROMIUM_sync_control
      - EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness
      - EGL_EXT_image_dma_buf_import
      - EGL_KHR_cl_event2
      - EGL_KHR_create_context
      - EGL_KHR_fence_sync
      - EGL_KHR_get_all_proc_addresses
      - EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace
      - EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image
      - EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image
      - EGL_KHR_image
      - EGL_KHR_image_base
      - EGL_KHR_image_pixmap
      - EGL_KHR_reusable_sync
      - EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context
      - EGL_KHR_wait_sync
      - EGL_MESA_configless_context
      - EGL_MESA_drm_image
      - EGL_MESA_image_dma_buf_export
      - EGL_NOK_swap_region
      - EGL_NOK_texture_from_pixmap
      - EGL_NV_post_sub_buffer
      - EGL_WL_bind_wayland_display
  gles2:
    vendor: X.Org
    vendor: OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 Mesa 12.0.6
    extensions:
      - GL_EXT_blend_minmax
      - GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
      - GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
      - GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias
      - GL_OES_byte_coordinates
      - GL_OES_fixed_point
      - GL_OES_stencil_wrap
      - GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture
      - GL_OES_query_matrix
      - GL_OES_read_format
      - GL_OES_single_precision
      - GL_OES_draw_texture
      - GL_OES_point_size_array
      - GL_OES_point_sprite
      - GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888
      - GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
      - GL_OES_depth24
      - GL_OES_element_index_uint
      - GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap
      - GL_OES_framebuffer_object
      - GL_OES_mapbuffer
      - GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8
      - GL_OES_stencil8
      - GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar
      - GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat
      - GL_OES_texture_npot
      - GL_OES_EGL_image
      - GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil
      - GL_OES_texture_cube_map
      - GL_APPLE_texture_max_level
      - GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer
      - GL_EXT_read_format_bgra
      - GL_OES_blend_equation_separate
      - GL_OES_blend_func_separate
      - GL_OES_blend_subtract
      - GL_OES_EGL_image_external
      - GL_OES_EGL_sync
      - GL_OES_vertex_array_object
      - GL_EXT_map_buffer_range
      - GL_KHR_debug
      - GL_OES_surfaceless_context
      - GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp
```

Answer (score 2):

#### This answer was originally posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/903959/665251) by [Brittany](https://askubuntu.com/users/677334/brittany)

first run session manager by entering this command

```
anbox session-manager
```

and then click on the Anbox icon from launcher

Better way would be to add this service inside Startup Applications

to do that open Startup Applications > Add > in command write `anbox session-manager`

and you'd be able to use Anbox without running that command on every boot or keeping a minimised terminal windows.