# How to launch Anbox?

Tags: 17.04, anbox

I understand, that Anbox is in super alpha, but I need help. I cannot launch it. There is terminal entries:

```
$ anbox launch  
[EE 2017-04-27 16:03:20] [launch.cpp:76@operator()] Anbox session manager     service isn't running!  
$ anbox session-manager  
[EE 2017-04-27 16:03:44] [session_manager.cpp:119@operator()] Failed to start     as either binder or ashmem kernel drivers are not loaded
```

Comment: Did you run `sudo anbox-installer` after installing the Snap? The message is suggesting that the kernel modules did not load, perhaps they are not installed.

Comment: There's also this: https://askubuntu.com/a/903959/237387

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Ubuntu, just click on the Anbox icon in the dash.

It's supposed to automatically launch the 'anbox session-manager' and then the gui application window.

Currently it's broken for me and doesn't work in Ubuntu (bitten by bug https://github.com/anbox/anbox/issues/367) :(

Comment: Not everybody uses icons.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the snap, `$ anbox.appmgr` is your friend.

Comment: at elementary os hera , anbox indeed didn't show up in the applications menu ,but this CLI command did initiate it .

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to load the kernel modules `ashmem` and `binder` by running

```
sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
sudo modprobe binder_linux
```

Comment: can you add some explanation? I don't even have such modules...

Comment: "modprobe: FATAL: Module binder_linux not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic"                                                                                                                  
This message is coming on my ubuntu 18.04

Comment: $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-generic anbox-modules-dkms

Answer (score 2):

Install DKMS package from PPA
In order to add the PPA to your Ubuntu system please run the following commands:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:morphis/anbox-support
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install linux-headers-generic anbox-modules-dkms

$ sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
$ sudo modprobe binder_linux
```

Now try to run Anbox, it will run without any issues ;)

Comment: On the first command for adding morphis PPA repsitory, I got this error through 22.04 Ubuntu terminal:
"ERROR: ppa 'morphis/anbox-support' not found (use --login if private)"

Answer (score 1):

In 18.04 I had to manually install the modules from [andbox-modules repo](https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules); basically

```
git clone https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules
cd andbox-modules
./INSTALL.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Its not working yet, here's what I tried...

- I am using ubuntu 17.4
- I started from [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/run-android-apps-games-linux/) :

  - Using e.g. synaptics installed snapd, anbox
- Tried anbox:

Version was:

```
$anbox version
anbox 0.0~git20190124-1-Ubuntu
```

Anbox did not run, there was a module missing:

```
$ anbox session-manager [ 2020-01-21 18:25:14]
[session_manager.cpp:130@operator()] Failed to start as either binder or ashmem kernel drivers are not loaded
```

Ok, checking if the kernel drivers are there...

```
$ ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory
/dev/ashmem
```

Module binder is not there...

```
$ sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
$ sudo modprobe binder_linux
$ ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory
/dev/ashmem
```

modprobe did not solve my problem...

- Going for manual install of anbox from [github](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/docs/install.md).

The instructions there give a ppa for the modules, but at present ubuntu does not accept using it because it says it is unsecured. From the comments, the modules are maintained [here](https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules)

```
sudo apt install dkms
... 
dkms is already the newest version (2.7.1-4ubuntu2.1).
dkms set to manually installed.

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
... 
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version (5.3.0.26.30).
```

ok, now get source code...

```
$ cd /tmp
/tmp$ git clone https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules.git
/tmp$ cd anbox-modules/
```

Modprobe works, lsmod shows the modules loaded, but `/dev/binder` is still not there... :S